# I typically see code such as "object.property.sub-property", but can we go further such as "obj.prop.subprop1.subprop2.subprop3.subprop4, and so on."?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm learning javascript for a while now, and I typically see `object.property.sub-property` (e.g., `header.style.color`)

I've never seen code that are long such as `obj.prop.subprop1.subprop2.subprop3.subprop4.subprop5... so on` (trying to exaggerate).

Is this actually valid? If so, can you give an example where it's actually being use in real application?

Is it a sensible thing to do?

Comment: You can go as many levels as you need. The value of a property can be another object. And the value of its property can be a third object. And so on.

Comment: For instance, `element.parent.parent.parent.parent.property.style.subproperty` will set the style of the great-great grandparent element.

Comment: This happens all the time in applications that use complex nested objects. Often there will be arrays of other objects nested inside the object. Take a look at the JSON responses from some APIs.

Comment: Yes, this would be valid code, and it does happen. But rarely. A quick evaluation of our codebase gives: ~20k single-level property accesses, ~3.9k double-level accesses, ~970 triple-level, ~700 fourth-level. Now nearly all of those 700 amount to an ORM that likes the pattern `db.schemas.public.tables.users.insert()` (fifth!). The remaining ones are often method calls on the object, given your example: `header.style.color.toHex()` is 4 levels already. Or `document.body.classList.add(…)`. And then there's deep data access, like `context.activity.channelData.team.id` (M$ teams, lookin at you…)

Comment: However, while in OOP it is normal and sensible to deeply "nest" (or rather, "link") objects, most of the time you never access so many levels all in the same single expression. You'd introduce a temporary variable, then further access properties of that variable. In data objects it's also normal to have objects nested in arrays, forcing you to iterate them and thereby introduce a variable for the array element.